# WCF Message Size Specification

Tags: wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

What is Maximum message size (in MB) of incoming and outgoing messages.

maxReceivedMessageSize (what is MAX value we can set with this configuration for basichttp binding)

Answer (score 0):

Run the test client and scroll to the bottom. If you double click the Config File node you will see the XML representation. As you can see the `maxReceivedMessageSize` is 65536.
the limit is `Int64.MaxValue1` which is: 9223372036854775807.